# How to get the equivalent of tcsh's enhanced completion in bash?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In the [tcsh manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh), the effects of `set complete = enhance` are defined as follows:

> [...] completion 1) ignores case and 2) considers periods, hyphens and underscores ('.', '-' and '_') to be word separators and hyphens and underscores to be equivalent.

As regards 1), I know that `readline` can be configured to ignore case through `set completion-ignore-case on`. So my question concerns only 2).

For instance, if I have a directory containing several files with similar basenames but different extensions like this:

```
$ ls
file0.dat file1.dat file2.dat files.sh
```

then I want the shell to be able to complete on file extension:

```
$ cat .sh<TAB>
$ cat files.sh
```

Is there a way to achieve or, at least, mimic this behavior in `bash`?

**EDIT**

Following first answers, here are other examples that show more accurately how the `tcsh` feature works:

```
$ ls
abc.foo abc.bar cab.foo cab.bar
$ cat a.f<TAB>
$ cat abc.foo
```

or:

```
$ cat .b<TAB>
abc.bar cab.bar
$ cat .bar
```

Actually, `tcsh` completes both basename and extension. The behavior intended here is to list the possibilities if more than one, as usual with TAB completion, not to insert them all.

Comment: You can do it in by `cat *.sh<TAB>` but usually bash is used in other way `cat f<TAB>` produce `cat file` then `cat file<s><TAB>` produce `cat files.sh`

Comment: @Costas what version of bash are you using? `cat *.sh<TAB>` does not work for me on `GNU bash, version 4.3.30`. Do you have an option set perhaps?

Comment: @terdon `echo $BASH_VERSION
 
4.3.11(1)-release` `echo $-  
himBH`

Comment: @Costas And you can expand globs with tab? I think I remember being able to do this but I can't get it to work now. It would be great if you could post an answer explaining it. Have a look at the output of `shopt` in case there is anything relevant there. Perhaps the functionality has been removed in the newer versions.

Comment: @terdon `shopt -p | sed -En 's/.*-s //p'` `checkwinsize
cmdhist
complete_fullquote
expand_aliases
extglob
extquote
force_fignore
histappend
interactive_comments
progcomp
promptvars
sourcepath
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not quite what you need but close. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd> shortcut (`C-x g` in emacsspeak) shortcut will list the expansinos of a glob. So, in your example:

```
$ cat *.b*<Ctrl><x><g>
abc.bar  cab.bar
```

So, unlike what you describe for `tcsh`, this needs a valid glob. In other words, it does the equivalent of

```
$ echo *.b*
```

Note that the shortcut is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> together, then releasing them and pressing <kbd>g</kbd>.

This is documented in `man bash`:

```
   glob-list-expansions (C-x g)
          The list  of  expansions  that  would  have  been  generated  by
          glob-expand-word  is  displayed,  and the line is redrawn.  If a
          numeric argument is supplied, an  asterisk  is  appended  before
          pathname expansion.
```

Comment: That is OK for the simple case where there is only one possible completion. But inserting all of them when there is more than one is not the behavior expected. I have edited my question accordingly. Sorry for not having been sufficiently clear in the original post.

Comment: @Paul-AntoineArras see updated answer. It's not quite as cool as what you describe but I think it's the best you can get in bash without scripting something yourself. If you do want to script it yourself, have a look at the `bash-completion` package, that might be a good start.